# What parameter should I feed to Frida `ObjC.api.class_addMethod()` to make it happy?

Tags: objective-c, frida

I want to use Frida to add a class method to the existing Objective C class on Mac OS. After I read the Frida [docs](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#objc), I tried the following code:

```
const NSString = ObjC.classes.NSString

function func (n) { console.log(n) }

var nativeCb = new NativeCallback(func, 'void', ['int'])

ObjC.api.class_addMethod(
  NSString.handle,
  ObjC.selector('onTest:'),
  nativeCb,
  ObjC.api.method_getTypeEncoding(nativeCb)
)
```

The above code looks straightforward. However, after the `ObjC.api.class_addMethod()` call, the attached App and the Frida REPL both froze, it looks that the pointers are not right.

I have tried many possible parameter values for a whole night but still can figure the problem out. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two issues:

- `method_getTypeEncoding()` can only be called on a `Method`, which the `NativeCallback` is not. You could pass it the handle of an existing Objective-C method that has the same signature as the one you're adding, or use `Memory.allocUtf8String()` to specify your own signature from scratch.
- Objective-C methods, at the C ABI level, have two implicit arguments preceding the method's arguments. These are:

  - 1. `self`: The class/instance the method is being invoked on.
  - 2. `_cmd`: The selector.

Here's a complete example in TypeScript:

```
const { NSAutoreleasePool, NSString } = ObjC.classes;

const onTest = new NativeCallback(onTestImpl, "void", ["pointer", "pointer", "int"]);

function onTestImpl(selfHandle: NativePointer, cmd: NativePointer, n: number): void {
    const self = new ObjC.Object(selfHandle);
    console.log(`-[NSString onTestImpl]\n\tself="${self.toString()}"\n\tn=${n}`);
}

function register(): void {
    ObjC.api.class_addMethod(
        NSString,
        ObjC.selector("onTest:"),
        onTest,
        Memory.allocUtf8String("v@:i"));
}

function test(): void {
    const pool = NSAutoreleasePool.alloc().init();
    try {
        const s = NSString.stringWithUTF8String_(Memory.allocUtf8String("yo"));
        s.onTest_(42);
    } finally {
        pool.release();
    }
}

function exposeToRepl(): void {
    const g = global as any;
    g.register = register;
    g.test = test;
}

exposeToRepl();
```

You can paste it into https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example, and then with one terminal running `npm run watch` you can load it into a running app using the REPL: `frida -n Telegram -l _agent.js`. From the REPL you can then call `register()` to plug in the new method, and `test()` to take it for a spin.

Comment: BTW: I'm a TypeScript fan too and I fall in love with [frida-agent-example](https://github.com/oleavr/frida-agent-example) once I used it. ;-D